# How to define the $f$ function to apply Ito's lemma?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, itos-lemma, homework

\begin{equation}
Z(t) = \exp (a W(t))
\end{equation}

I am asked to find $dZ$. I am pretty sure it can be done using Ito's lemma. But in all my textbook (Bjork) examples Ito's lemma is giving from a $dZ$ function and not the other way around.

My question: I want to use Ito's lemma to find $dZ$. How do I define my $f$ (from the standard Ito's lemma formulation) function?

Comment: With a bit of effort you should find this in pretty much any textbook. I random pickup up Volume II of Shreve's Stochastic Calculus for Finance. The first worked example in Section 4.4.3 is pretty much already what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't have that book. I have taken this example from Bjork's book. But I still have trouble understanding how to define the "f" function

Comment: Your self-study tag contradicts your own statement that this is homework. I am voting to close this question as too basic. You should be able to infer it from the worked-out Example 4.13 in Bjoerk's book.

Comment: In that example Bjork sets sigma=1 and mu=0 ( standard Ito's lemma formulation ). I don't quite follow that logic.

Comment: It is a basic question, but basic stochastic calculus not basic finance strictly speaking. I think it can serve the community. But no offense @LocalVolatility, it is a really borderline question. I hope you won't mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, the variable $Z_t$ is a function of $W_t$, which is the stochastic variable.

Therefore, you can see $Z_t$ as $f(W_t) = \exp(aW_t)$.

The rest is a trivial application of Ito's lemma to find $dZ_t=df(W_t)$.

Comment: I get it, thx..